# Change flash message color from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, flash-message

I have a list of symbols that correspond to various flash messages:

```
:is_self
:already_exist
:already_added 
:invited 
:added
```

Every time I run my method, variable `answer` is assigned one of these symbols. I assigned to variable `message` the flash message I want to display:

```
message = t("flash.#{answer.to_s}")
```

This works fine. At the end of my method, I have something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to url, flash: { info: message } }
end
```

I would like to change the flash message color (switch between `info: success: error:`). How can I set a hash variable that would contain the right color for the flash message? I tried something like:

```
new_hash = { :is_self => "info:" , :already_exist => "info:" , :already_added => "info:", :invited => "success:", :added => "success:", }
flash_color = new_hash[answer]
```

And then:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to url, flash: { flash_color message } }
end
```

But I won't work. I have no idea how to give the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumed, if you are using [twitter bootstrap for style flash](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#Alert), You can save your selection style on `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
    when :notice then "alert alert-info"
    when :success then "alert alert-success"
    when :error then "alert alert-warning"
    when :alert then "alert alert-danger"
    end
  end
end
```

create file `_flash_message.html.erb` on folder layout and paste this

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert <%= flash_class(key).to_s %> fade in">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and to call the flash you just render in view

```
<%= render 'layouts/flash_message' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the syntax a little. The mapping you've got initially:

```
{ info: message }
```

is a hash mapping the symbol `:info` to the value of `message`. It could be written `{ :info => message }`

In your hash `new_hash` you're including the colon, which is used in the ruby 1.9 hash syntax to indicate a symbol, in a string. I expect you're getting syntax errors as you're no longer setting up a hash in a valid way.

I think you'll need to use the more traditional hash syntax and specify the symbols in your `new_hash`. Something like this should work:

```
new_hash = { 
  :is_self => :info, 
  :already_exist => :info, 
  :already_added => :info, 
  :invited => :success, 
  :added => :success, 
}
```

with:

```
flash_color = new_hash[answer]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to url, flash: { flash_color => message } }
end
```

P.S. It's also slightly confusing that you're calling it `flash_color` - the colour is only really a by-product of it being styled on the front end. They are really just keys in the flash hash.